# AWS S3 C++: Should I use UploadFile() or PutObject() for uploading a file? Where are the differences?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For a new project we have to upload files to AWS S3. The C++ SDK let us do this in 2 ways.
The first way is using the Transfermanager and its UploadFile()-method.
Secondly we can use a Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest().

Are there any important differences between these to methods? I have read that putObject() automatically calculates the hashsum and provides a check of the hashum if the file is uploaded. What about the UploadFile()?

```
std::shared_ptr<Aws::Transfer::TransferHandle> handle = 
transfermanager->UploadFile(Aws::String("C:/test.txt"),  
Aws::String("bucketName"), 
Aws::String(key), Aws::String("multipart/form-data"), metadata);

-----------------

auto request = Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest();
request.WithBucket("bucketName").WithKey(key);
request.SetBody(input_data);
request.SetMetadata(metadata);

s3client->PutObject(request);
```

Both results in an upload of the file to the S3 bucket. I can't tell any differences.